# External play button iPad

Tags: javascript, html, video

Is it possible to make an external play button for a video without the play button in the video?
For example when you want to start a youtube video you see a red button in the middle of it. I want that hidden and a button outside of the video to start the video. It doesn't matter what video player it is.

I want to do this because iPad does not allow autoplay. And using the external button I want to trick it to autoplay.

This is a website that does "autoplay" on the iPad.
http://24hoursofhappy.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why YouTube doesn't allow autoplay on mobile/tablet devices, video's use up alot of bandwith which may become expensive for the user.

U can trick it like u mentioned with a custom play button or even force it to start playing without a custom button. There is alot of detailed information on YouTube's API page.
Check out this page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/

I'd refrain from always autoplaying a video though if not just for bandwith reasons. In your case u could check if the device is a tablet.

Comment: Yes I did try that but it doesn't work for the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer for this using HTML5 videos. It allows me to use the control buttons externally so I can use an overlay and hide the overlay when the play button is clicked so it will seem like it is auot played.